# multiply and sum two dictionary list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
dict1={'NegSm': [1.0, 0.59375], 'NegBig': [1.0], 'NegMed': [1.0]}
dict2={'NegBig': [-21.666666666666668], 'NegMed': [-15.0], 'NegSm': [-6.0]}
```

I want to multiply every same keys together and sum them all

expected output

```
1.0*-6.0 + 0.59375*-6.0 + 1.0*-15 + 1.0*-21.66666666
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are the keys guaranteed to be exist in both dictionaries?

Answer (score 2):

```py
dict1 = {"NegSm": [1.0, 0.59375], "NegBig": [1.0], "NegMed": [1.0]}
dict2 = {"NegBig": [-21.666666666666668], "NegMed": [-15.0], "NegSm": [-6.0]}

out = 0
for k1, vals in dict1.items():
    for v1 in vals:
        for v2 in dict2[k1]:
            out += v1 * v2

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
-46.22916666666667
```

---

Or:

```py
out = sum(
    v1 * v2 for k1, vals in dict1.items() for v1 in vals for v2 in dict2[k1]
)

print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Andrej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67763430/4518341), just wanted to add a slightly different solution using a [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
from itertools import product

out = sum(
    v1*v2
    for k in dict1
    for v1, v2 in product(dict1[k], dict2[k]))

print(out)  #-> -46.22916666666667
```